# Should I store a list in memory or in a database and should I build a class to connect to DB?

Tags: c++, database, oop

I am writing a C++ program, I have a class that provides services for the rest of the clases in the program.

I am writing now the clases and the UML.
1) the class that I refer to has a task list that is changing over time and conditions are being checked on this list, I am thinking to keep it in a table in a databasse that every line in the table would represent a task, this way in case that the program crashes or stops working I can restore the last situation, the other option is to keep the task list in memory and keep a copy in the database.

the task list should be searched every second
Which approach is more recommended?

2) In order to write and to read to the database I can call the database directly from the class or build a database communication class, if I write a data communication class I need to give specific options and to build a mini server for this,
e.g. write a line to the database, read a line to the database, update only the first column etc..

what is the recommended approach for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Reasons for using a DB vs in-RAM storage:  1) you need persistence.  2) the amount of data is too large to fit comfortably in RAM.  As to your "database communication class" there are many ways to do this.  The usual scheme is to define structs/classes which closely map the structure of your table rows and provide functions to read/write entire objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the database is obvious and easy, and there are no performance problems, just do that. You're talking about running a query once/second, and maybe marking a task done or adding a new one every so often; even sqlite on a slow SMB share should be able to handle that just fine.

If you do need to optimize it, then there are two approaches: Either still with the database and cache it in-memory, or use memory as your primary storage and come up with a persistence mechanism that uses the database. But until you need to optimize it, don't.

Next, how should you do it? Your question makes it sound like you're thinking in terms of a whole three-tier system, with a "mini-server" sitting between the database server and your task list. There's really no need for that. What you want is a bespoke ORM, but that makes it sound more complicated than it is. All you're doing is writing a class that wraps a database connection and provides a handful of methods—`get_due`, `mark_done`, `add`, `get_next_id`—each of which maps SQL parameters to `Task` members. For example (with no error handling):

```
void mark_done(Task task) {
    db.execute("UPDATE Task SET done=true WHERE id=%s", task.id);
}
```

Three more methods like that, plus a constructor to connect to the database (including creating the `Task` table if it didn't already exist), and your class is done.

The reason you don't want to write the database stuff directly into `Task` is that you don't really have anywhere to store shared information like the database connection object; either you need globals (or class attributes, which are effectively globals), or you need copies in every single `Task` instance (or, really, weak references—which you're going to fake with either a reference or a raw pointer, either way leading to shutdown problems somewhere down the line).

Finally, your whole reason for doing this is error recovery, and databases do a great job of journaling so nothing ever gets inconsistent, but you do have to make sure to structure your app to take advantage of that. For example, you may want to mark all the now-due tasks "in process", then process them, then mark them all "done"; that way, at recovery time, you know exactly which tasks may or may not have been done, and can act appropriately. The more steps you can commit to the database, the less data loss you have to deal with—but of course the more code you have to write, and the slower it gets. So, do as much as necessary, but no more.

Answer (score 0):

Saving information in Database just to recover crashed information may be bit of an overkill.

You ideally want to serialize the list and save it - as binary, xml or csv based values. This can be done based on a timer or certain events in your applications.

Databases may also be used if you can come up with a structure that looks exactly similar to tables - so that you can do one-to-one mapping between the objects and probably write SQL queries easily. But keep that on a separate layer for abstraction.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, this can be dangerous and leave you in an inconsistent state that can't be recovered from cleanly (unless you write your own lightweight journaling in front of the database's). For example, a payment system that got through 17 payments, wrote to the database, go through another 14, crashed without writing to the database, then restarted would pay the first 14 again, which would probably get you in a lot of trouble.